# Grails controller actions per environment

Tags: grails, controller

Is it possible to have certain controller actions only exist under certain environments?  E.g.,

```
def list() {
    ....
}

Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
    development {
        def testList() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not work :/

Comment: It's right in the example of the official documentation... http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/if.html

Comment: That is for views. I'm talking about controller actions. I want it to essentially appear that the action in question does not exist outside of development.

Comment: No, but if you describe why you think you want to do that, there is almost certainly a better way to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish.  Since that is likely going to lead to a discussion, our Google group is probably a better forum.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grails-dev-discuss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have certain controller actions only exist under
>   certain environments?

No.

You are probably looking for other mechanisms to restrict access to a controller action such as [filters](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) or [controller interceptors](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors).  These mechanisms can be used to render/trigger a 404 or other error response.